# Is it "go on a rampage" or "go on the rampage"?

Tags: articles, definite-article, indefinite-article

I read a headline in *"The Hindu"* which was:

> Pant goes on **the** Rampage as Capitals crush Mumbai

We use article "the" before a noun which we've talked about or mentioned earlier or before a particular thing. But then on googling this phrase I saw a lot of dictionaries (Cambridge dictionary, Free dictionaries) using only "the" before "rampage". Why is it so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can say either "on the rampage" or "on a rampage". Both are grammatical and convey the same meaning.

The noun *rampage* is both a countable noun and an uncountable noun. In American English, it's chiefly treated as a countable noun, especially in a singular form. So we say "on a rampage", but "on the rampage" is also acceptable. In British English, it's chiefly used as an uncountable noun. So we say "on the rampage", but "on a rampage" is also acceptable.

According to [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on%20a%20rampage%2Con%20the%20rampage&year_start=1920&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3), both the phrases are almost equally common, but the Ngrams also show *on **a** rampage* favored in [American English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on%20a%20rampage%2Con%20the%20rampage&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3), and *on **the** rampage* favored in [British English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on%20a%20rampage%2Con%20the%20rampage&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3).

Answer (score 5):

In my experience "on a rampage" describes the actions of a person or entity, while "on the rampage" describes the state of a person or entity.

Example: "My boss went on a rampage and fired eight employees!" or "My boss is on the rampage, he just fired eight employees!".

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Go on a/the rampage both the versions are correct and are used according to the context.
 [go on a/the rampage](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/amp/english/go-on-a-the-rampage)

> The prisoners went on a rampage destroying everything in their way.